# Having combined sv_dependence shapviz plots with feature value color bar displayed once

Tags: r, ggplot2, shap

I'm trying to arrange three `sv_dependence()` plots from `shpaviz` in a single graph with `grid.arrange()`. I would like the feature value color scale to appear just once. Here is a reproducible code, with the result I obtained so far:

```
library(shapviz)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)

X_train <- data.matrix(`colnames<-`(replicate(26, rnorm(100)), LETTERS))
dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label = rnorm(100))
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 50)
shp <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_train)

p_a <- sv_importance(shp, kind = "beeswarm", show_numbers = TRUE, max_display = 15, color_bar_title=NULL)
p_b <- sv_importance(shp, kind = "beeswarm", show_numbers = TRUE, max_display = 15, color_bar_title=NULL)
p_c <- sv_importance(shp, kind = "beeswarm", show_numbers = TRUE, max_display = 15)
grid.arrange(p_a,p_b,p_c,nrow=1)
```

[image]

How can I make the third graph the same dimension of the other two while having the feature value color bar displayed?

Comment: You started out so well (using set.seed(.) to create a reproducible example with a toy dataset) but then you used functions  with no `library` call to load them.

Comment: You are right, correcting it right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to switch to `patchwork` to glue your plots together.

```
library(patchwork)

p_a + p_b + p_c
```

[image]